# Converting partial XML (Node List) to a String

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have a need to extract a part of XML tree (everything under `root`) and convert it to a string.  (The result string will be later pasted inside `XSL-FO` XSLT file.)

The above functionality is a part of Java 6 application.  I use [`org.w3c.dom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) and [`javax.xml.transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html). Still in the debugging process.

```
// ...

// Extract all child notes of root from foDoc
// and convert the result to String
Node root = foDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("*","root").item(0);
NodeList body = root.getChildNodes();
String foResult;

try {
    foResult = nodeListToString(body);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    logger.error(e);

    foResult = "";
}
// ...
```

```
private static String nodeListToString(NodeList nodes) throws TransformerException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int len = nodes.getLength();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++ i) {
        result.append(nodeToString(nodes.item(i)));
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TransformerException {
    StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
    Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    xform.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buf));
    return(buf.toString());
}
```

My questions:

1. Assuming that there will always be exactly one `root` node, how reliable is my code in extracting **everything** under it?
2. Am I missing any edge cases?
3. Anything just plain wrong?

Please disregard any exception handling inadequacies.

**Edited** on 10/06/2015

Since my originally posted code had a "*just plain wrong*" part, I've fixed it. There were no answers based on the old code.

Comment: How committed are you to using DOM? I seldom just jump ion and recommend alternative tools, but, I maintain the JDOM library, and this sort of activity is easy if you can use JDOM instead..... just saying.

Comment: @rolfl - Thank you for the reference.  I will keep it in mind for future projects.  This time I am making a small change to a plugin for a huge system and need to stay within its existing tooling.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the documentation for
[`Transformer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html),
where it says:

> A Transformer may be used multiple times. Parameters and output
>   properties are preserved across transformations.

, I'd say that not only can the `Transformer` object be reused across
multiple nodes, but you should also be able to use a single
`StringWriter` instead of recreating it for every node; same goes for
the `DOMSource` actually:

```java
private static String nodeListToString(NodeList nodes) throws TransformerException {
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        source.setNode(nodes.item(i));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

That said, I'm only guessing that this should work.

Also, the `len` variable is probably going to be inlined automatically
anyway, though you could check that with a disassembler just to be sure
(it wouldn't make that much of a difference I suspect).

Otherwise looks good to me; if you've tested it with all kinds of node types and the output looks good, then I'd say that should work IMHO.

Comment: I use `nodeToString()` in other places of my code as well.

Comment: Then keep it in addition to this `nodeListToString`? I'm just assuming that inlining and removing allocations helps with bigger documents.

Comment: I second that it looks strange to build a string in a `StringWriter` just so that it can be appended to a `StringBuilder` in the caller. It would be better to reuse the `StringWriter`. You could pass the `StreamResult` object as a 2nd parameter into `nodeListToString`